# Writing to an excel using Apache POI corrupts the excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to write to excel using Apache POI. The code (below) executes fine, but when I am trying to open the excel, it is showing that the data inside the excel has been corrupted and it cannot be opened.

Excel version : Microsoft Office Excel 2007 and Microsoft Office Excel 2003 (tried both)

Apache POI Version: 3.6

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class WriteExcel{

    public String FilePath;
    XSSFWorkbook wb= null;
    XSSFSheet ws= null;
    XSSFRow xr=null;
    XSSFCell xc=null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;

    public WriteExcel(String FilePath) throws IOException

    {
        this.FilePath=FilePath;
        fout=new FileOutputStream(FilePath);
        wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
        wb.write(fout);

    }

    //Write to a specific Cell

    public void writeToCell(String SheetName, int RowNum, int ColNum, String Data) throws IOException
    {
        ws=wb.createSheet(SheetName);
        xr=ws.createRow(RowNum);
        xc=xr.createCell(ColNum);
        xc.setCellValue(Data);
        fout.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        WriteExcel WE= new WriteExcel("E://Learning//Learning//SoapUI//TestFiles//Write.xls");
        WE.writeToCell("Sheet1", 2, 2, "Pi");
        System.out.println("Written");

    }


}
```

[image: Image1]; [image: Image2]; [image: Image3]

I believe the  the code is fine because every time I am executing the code, the "Date Modified" shows the latest time stamp; so I suspect there might be something with versioning of either Microsoft Office (Excel) or Apache POI.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your excel to disk after you create the sheets, rows and cells.

```
public WriteExcel(String FilePath) throws IOException

{
    this.FilePath=FilePath;
}

//Write to a specific Cell

public void writeToCell(String SheetName, int RowNum, int ColNum, String Data) throws IOException
{
    fout=new FileOutputStream(FilePath);
    wb=new XSSFWorkbook();
    ws=wb.createSheet(SheetName);
    xr=ws.createRow(RowNum);
    xc=xr.createCell(ColNum);
    xc.setCellValue(Data);
    wb.write(fout);
    fout.close();
}
```

Comment: I created the an excel (.xlsx) programmatically and was found corrupted. But after creating at least one sheet on that it removed the corruption on excel file.